# VueJs3 Cli project, how to append global service methods

Tags: vuejs3

I recently downloaded a developers [Modal Dialog](https://codeburst.io/create-reusable-modals-using-vue-js-309eff9579bd).  His code is designed and described to be an add on to an existing project. (In other words, he does not modify the original main.js file... I don't understand if this is the right or wrong approach.)

In my code, Vue and createApp were created in main.js when the project was created.  In the modal dialog code, the developer did not start the creation of his project by creating a CLI project but rather as a simple standalone project (no CLI).  As you can see below, the developer of the modal introduces a global service in which he appears to redefine Vue and adds a method "open" which returns a Promise.

With the modal added to my project as documented, I get an error pointing to the the modal.service.js file which says "TypeError: default is not a constructor" on line 2 and it seems to be breaking webpack.

I'm assuming the only difference between the modal dialog tutorial/sample code and my project is the developer did not start out by creating a CLI project.

In a CLI project how does one preform basically the same functionally, add a global method to "app" that can be called on from any component in the project?

Here is my CLI main.js file:

```
import { createApp, reactive, computed, VueElement } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './assets/styles.css'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

This is the modal.service.js file which generates the error on line two:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export default new Vue({
methods: {
  open(component, props = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.$emit('open', { component, props, resolve, reject });
    });
  }
}
})
```

Then in the developers ModalRoot.vue file where the service method gets called the following code exists:

```
import ModalService from '../services/modal.service';
import Modal from '../components/Modal.vue';

export default {
  components: { Modal },
  data() {
    return {
      modal: {},
    }
  },
  created() {
    ModalService.$on('open', ({ component, props, resolve, reject }) => {
      this.modal = {
        component,
        props,
        close: value => {
          this.modal = {};
          resolve(value);
        },
        dismiss: reason => {
          this.modal = {};
          reject(reason);
        },
      };
    });
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to add global methods to Vue CLI projects such as this developer has done in his modal.service.js file?

Thank you in advance to anyone that can show me how to add the desired functionally to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Modal Dialog](https://codeburst.io/create-reusable-modals-using-vue-js-309eff9579bd) I chose to use seems to use syntax defined for Vue 2 and is not compatible with Vue 3.

Reviewing the official [Vuejs.org](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#overview) website about migration from Vue2 to Vue3, I discovered that **$on** as shown in the ModalRoot.vue listing above, is a feature that has been removed from Vue3.  (Scroll down to the part about "Breaking Changes".)

Although I'm no expert at Vue3 and have never worked in Vue2, it is now clear, I need to look for another modal dialog solution or write mine own from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a separate app where you follow the tutorial exactly and see if it works. If it does, use that learned information in your own app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm assuming your sample works if the project is created exactly the way shown in the video and article your wrote.  Both of those are really great but they lack being able to add your functionally to a VueJS 3 app that was created as an standard out of the box CLI project.  I understand if you have no interest in updating your article, video but if there is a simple answer... modal.service > export default new Vue( breaks the project.

Comment: I believe the simple answer is, your solution for a modal is only compatible with Vue 2.